# How to pass a value to the variable outside each() loop in cypress

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I have each() loop that is going through elements:

```js
let counter = 0

cy.get(selector).then(items => {
  cy.wrap(items).each(($item) => {
    --snip--
    counter += 1
  })
})

cy.wrap(items).should('have.length', counter)
```

**Expected result:**
Add +1 value to the *counter* variable each time you pass the loopy and in final assertion length of *items* should be equal to *counter*.

**Actual result:**
+1 value is not added to the counter variable when you pass the loop and length of *items* is always equal to 0 in final assertion even if length of *items* > 0

How can I pass a value e.g. +1 to the variable outside of the each() loop?

I could not find an answer in the existing topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are directly checking the number of items, you can directly do this:

```js
cy.get(selector).should('have.length', 6)
```

If you want to do the counter approach you can do this:

```js
let counter = 0

cy.get(selector)
  .each(($item) => {
    //--snip--
    counter += 1
  })
  .then(() => {
    cy.get(selector).should('have.length', counter)
  })
```

Comment: The second one works as expected.